# describe "this._sender" in Javascript MVC EventDispatcher?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

### Hi there

I don't get it the role of `sender` parameter in below Code.

Event.js::--

```
var Event = function (sender) {
    this._sender = sender;
    this._listeners = [];
}

Event.prototype = {

    attach: function (listener) {
        this._listeners.push(listener);
    },

    notify: function (args) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this._listeners.length; i += 1) {
            this._listeners[i](this._sender, args);
         }
    }

};
```

And in the

Model.js::--

```
var Model = function(){
    this.addTaskEvent = new Event(this);
    this.setTasksAsCompletedEvent = new Event(this);
    this.deleteTasksEvent = new Event(this);
}
```

Why is the `this` of the Model needed in the *Event.js*?

Will someone please **describe** it?

**Thanks** in advance

Comment: It's a convention to tell that the variables have local scope.

Comment: what variables have local scope?It's an EventDispatcher for Javascript Observer pattern.

Comment: It's not related to observer pattern, rather releted to scoping in js

Comment: I edited the Code.Now it makes more sense.The Event.js contains the Event constructor which is **EventDispatcher** in MVC. But why do we need to give `this` as the sender from the Model.That's what i'm trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

This code is an example of object oriented programming in Javascript. The constructor in this example is the Event function. In order to access the sender parameter in the prototype methods, you have to attach sender to a property on the constructor. Without that step, sender will be undefined. That is why they set this._sender equal to sender.

Also, your way of creating methods is called Pseudoclassical instantiation. There is a great article about javascript instantiation http://callmenick.com/post/instantiation-patterns-in-javascript here.

Comment: That's not the catch. **What is the role of the sender in the Whole Event Class?**

Comment: It looks like this._listeners is an array of functions and the sender is passed in as an argument to the listeners function.

Comment: Yes `this._listeners` is an array of listeners which listen to the Model's Event and will be notified whenever the `Model` changes or Updated.

**It's an Observer pattern in MVC**